# Custom Arabic datepicker in UIPickerView

Tags: objective-c, nsdate, uipickerview, uidatepicker

i am trying to implement an **arabic** datepicker. after a small research (and found nothing) i found this as the only solution: (am i right?)

create a custom `UIPickerView` with 3 components for the days, months, and years.

the real problem is that i want to set a maximum date, for example `[NSDate date]`.

do i have to code it all, or there is a simpler way of doing it... anything will help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the approach *madhu* proposed was not general, i finally made my own **Arabic** date picker.

These are the .h and the .m files that may help someone someday... an instance of these files is added as a subview to another view containing various other cell types.

the code is very messy, and may contain super ugly and deep leeks, but it works (for now).

**dateCell.h:**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface dateCell : UIViewController<UIActionSheetDelegate,UIPickerViewDelegate,UIPickerViewDataSource> {

    IBOutlet UILabel *l;
    IBOutlet UITextField *t;
    IBOutlet UIButton *b;

    UIPickerView *picker;
    UIActionSheet *actionSheet;

    NSDictionary *numbers;
    NSDictionary *months;
    int year;
    int month;
    int day;

    //properties
    NSString *str;
    NSString *name;
    NSString *limit;
    BOOL save;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *l;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *t;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *b;

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *str;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *limit;
@property (nonatomic) BOOL save;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIView* target;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDictionary *numbers;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDictionary *months;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIPickerView *picker;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIActionSheet *actionSheet;

-(IBAction) bPressed;
-(void) setTarget:(UIView *)tar;
-(void)showPicker;
-(int)getYear;
-(NSString*)translateYear:(int)iYear;
-(int) getDay;
-(int) getMonth;
-(int)getNumberOfDaysinYear:(int)y andMonth:(int)m;
- (void)changeDateInLabel:(id)sender;

@end
```

**dateCell.m:**

```
#import "dateCell.h"


@implementation dateCell
@synthesize l,t,b;
@synthesize name, limit, save,str,target,numbers,months,picker,actionSheet;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

-(void)loadView{
    [super loadView];
    l.text=str;


    NSArray *aDays=[[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"١",@"٢",@"٣",@"٤",@"٥",@"٦",@"٧",@"٨",@"٩",@"٠",nil] autorelease];
    NSArray *eDays=[[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3",@"4",@"5",@"6",@"7",@"8",@"9",@"0",nil] autorelease];
    numbers=[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:aDays forKeys:eDays];

    NSArray *aMonths=[[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"يناير",@"فبراير",@"مارس",@"أبريل",@"مايو",@"يونيو",@"يولي",@"أغسطس",@"سبتمبر",@"أكتوبر",@"نوفمبر",@"ديسمبر",nil] autorelease];
    NSArray *eMonths=[[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"0",@"1",@"2",@"3",@"4",@"5",@"6",@"7",@"8",@"9",@"10",@"11",nil] autorelease];
    months=[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:aMonths forKeys:eMonths];

}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc. that aren't in use.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
    [l release];
    [t release];
    [b release];
    [name release];
    [limit release];
    [str release];
    [target release];
    [numbers release];
    [months release];
    [picker release];
    [actionSheet release];
}


/*§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~
                                    Controls
 §~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~*/

-(IBAction) bPressed{
    [self showPicker];
}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    [self showPicker];
    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}

/*§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~
                                    picker handeling methods
 §~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~*/

-(void) setTarget:(UIView *)tar{
    target=tar;
}

-(void)showPicker{
    actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"select a date"
                                              delegate:self
                                     cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                     otherButtonTitles:nil];

    picker = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,40,0,0)];
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
    year=[self getYear];
    month=[self getMonth];
    day=[self getDay];
    [picker selectRow:year inComponent:0 animated:NO];
    [picker selectRow:(day+(9300/2)) inComponent:2 animated:NO];
    [picker selectRow:(month-1+(9600/2)) inComponent:1 animated:NO];
    [actionSheet addSubview:picker];

    UISegmentedControl *closeButton = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"OK"]];
    closeButton.momentary = YES; 
    closeButton.frame = CGRectMake(260, 7.0f, 50.0f, 30.0f);
    closeButton.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;
    closeButton.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    [closeButton addTarget:self action:@selector(dismissActionSheet) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [actionSheet addSubview:closeButton];
    [closeButton release];

    [actionSheet showInView:[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow];
    [actionSheet setBounds:CGRectMake(0,0,320,469)];
    actionSheet.autoresizingMask=UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin
    |UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;
    [picker release];
    [actionSheet release];  
}


- (void)changeDateInLabel:(id)sender{
    NSString *m = [[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%d", (month-1)] autorelease];
    m=[months objectForKey:m];
    NSString *y=[self translateYear:year];
    NSString *d=[self translateYear:day];
    NSString *dat = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ / %@ / %@",d,m,y];
    t.text=dat;

    NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
    NSString *realStr=[[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%d-%d-%d",year,month,day+1]autorelease];
    NSDate *realDate = [df dateFromString:realStr];
    [df release];
    NSLog(@"Date: %@", realDate);
    NSString *timestamp = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.0f", [realDate timeIntervalSince1970]];
    NSLog(@"millis: %@", timestamp);
}


-(void)dismissActionSheet{
    [actionSheet dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
}


/*§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~
                                    Date Methods
 §~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~*/

-(int) getYear{
    NSDateComponents *components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSDayCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit fromDate:[NSDate date]];
    return [components year];
}

-(NSString*)translateYear:(int)iYear{
    NSString *aYear=@"";
    while(iYear>0){
        int r=iYear%10;
        iYear=iYear/10;
        NSString *s = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", r];
        NSString *temp=[numbers objectForKey:s];
        aYear=[temp stringByAppendingString:aYear];
    }
    return aYear;
}

-(int) getDay{
    NSDateComponents *components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSDayCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit fromDate:[NSDate date]];
    return [components day];    
}

-(int) getMonth{
    NSDateComponents *components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSDayCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit fromDate:[NSDate date]];
    return [components month];  
}

-(int)getNumberOfDaysinYear:(int)y andMonth:(int)m{
    NSCalendar* cal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDateComponents* comps = [[[NSDateComponents alloc] init] autorelease];

    [comps setMonth:m];
    [comps setYear:y];

    NSRange range = [cal rangeOfUnit:NSDayCalendarUnit
                              inUnit:NSMonthCalendarUnit
                             forDate:[cal dateFromComponents:comps]];
    return range.length;
}


/*§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~
                                picker delegate methods
 §~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~§~*/

- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView;{
    return 3;
}

- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component{
    int d=[self getDay];
    int y=[self getYear];
    int m=[self getMonth];
    day=[picker selectedRowInComponent:2]%31;
    if(day==0){
        day=31;
    }
    month=([picker selectedRowInComponent:1]%12)+1;
    year=[picker selectedRowInComponent:0];
    if(year>y){
        year=y;
        [picker selectRow:y inComponent:0 animated:YES];
        [picker selectRow:(d+(9300/2)) inComponent:2 animated:YES];
        [picker selectRow:(m-1+(9600/2)) inComponent:1 animated:YES];
    }
    else{
        if(month>m && year==y){
            month=m;
            [picker selectRow:(m-1+(9600/2)) inComponent:1 animated:YES];
            [picker selectRow:(d+(9300/2)) inComponent:2 animated:YES];
        }
        else{
            int total=[self getNumberOfDaysinYear:year andMonth:month];
            if((day>total)||(day>d && month==m && year==y)){
                day=d;
                [picker selectRow:(d+(9300/2)) inComponent:2 animated:YES];
            }
        }
    }
    [picker reloadComponent:0];
    [picker reloadComponent:1];
    [picker reloadComponent:2];
    [self changeDateInLabel:nil];
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component{
    switch (component) {
        case 0:{
            return 4000;
            break;
        }
        case 1:{
            return 12*800;
            break;
        }
        case 2:{
             return 31*300;
            break;  
        }
        default:{
            return 0;
            break;
        }
    }
}

- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view {
    UILabel *pickerLabel = (UILabel *)view;
    if ((pickerLabel == nil) || ([pickerLabel class] != [UILabel class])) { //newlabel
        CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 75, 32.0);
        pickerLabel = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:frame] autorelease];
        pickerLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight;
        pickerLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        pickerLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:22];
    } 
    switch (component) {
        case 0:{
            [pickerLabel setText:[self translateYear:row]];         
            int y=[self getYear];
            if(row==y){
                pickerLabel.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];
            }
            else{
                if(row>y){
                    pickerLabel.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];
                }
                else{
                    pickerLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
                }
            }
            return pickerLabel;
            break;
        }
        case 1:{
            NSString *sM = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", (row%12)];
            [pickerLabel setText:[months objectForKey:sM]];
            int m=[self getMonth];
            int y=[self getYear];
            if(y<=year){
                if(((row%12)+1)==m){
                    pickerLabel.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];
                }
                else{
                    if(((row%12)+1)>m){
                        pickerLabel.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];
                    }
                    else{
                        pickerLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
                    }
                }
            }
            else{
                if(year<y){
                    if(((row%12)+1)==m){
                        pickerLabel.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];
                    }
                    else{
                        pickerLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
                    }
                }
            }
            return pickerLabel;
            break;
        }
        case 2:{
            int r;
            if((row%31)==0){
                r=31;
            }
            else{
                r=(row%31);
            }
            [pickerLabel setText:[self translateYear:r]];
            int d=[self getDay];
            int y=[self getYear];
            int m=[self getMonth];
            if(y<=year && m<=month){
                if(r==d){
                    pickerLabel.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];
                }
                else{
                    if(r>d){
                        pickerLabel.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];
                    }
                    else{
                        int total=[self getNumberOfDaysinYear:year andMonth:month];
                        if(r<=total){
                            pickerLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
                        }
                        else{
                            pickerLabel.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else{
                if(year<y || month<m){
                    if(r==d){
                        pickerLabel.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];
                    }
                    else{
                        int total=[self getNumberOfDaysinYear:year andMonth:month];
                        if(r<=total){
                            pickerLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
                        }
                        else{
                            pickerLabel.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return pickerLabel;
            break;  
        }
    }
    return nil;
}




@end
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

From http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIDatePicker_Class/Reference/UIDatePicker.html:

```
UIActionSheet *menu = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Date Picker" 
                                              delegate:self
                                     cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                     otherButtonTitles:nil];

// Add the picker
UIDatePicker *pickerView = [[UIDatePicker alloc] init];
pickerView.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;

//urmindate,urmaxdate are NSDate objects
[pickerView setMinimumDate:urmindate];

[pickerView setMinimumDate:urmaxdate];

[menu addSubview:pickerView];
[menu showInView:self.view];        
[menu setBounds:CGRectMake(0,0,320, 500)];

CGRect pickerRect = pickerView.bounds;
pickerRect.origin.y = -100;
pickerView.bounds = pickerRect;

[pickerView release];
[menu release];
```

From http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/reference/Foundation/Classes/NSLocale_Class/Reference/Reference.html:

> The locale property (and all other country specific format properties for that matter) defaults to the value returned by currentLocale, which in turns depends on the iphone's country settings, not the language settings. You need to set the appropriate country in the iphone general settings.

Comment: is there a way to set it programmatically?